# How can we use Spring Cloud Sleuth with spring MVC project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to use spring cloud sleuth with spring web mvc project. We are sending the request from spring web mvc to another spring boot project. I need to have the traceID and spanId to display in the UI. How can we achieve this?

EDIT

POM.xml for the spring boot application. I am using the latest version of Spring Boot and added the dependency of spring cloud sleuth.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Web MVC code: I am using spring rest template and calling the spring boot service from the spring web mvc application.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        logger.info("Hello from controller");
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8092/test", String.class);
        String response = entity.getBody();
        logger.info("Response from Service: "+ response);
        model.addAttribute("name", "Test");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your spring-boot project? Are you using RestTemplate?

Comment: Yes, I am using RestTemplate.

Comment: Can you share pom.xml of your spring-boot application and also sample code from your spring-mvc application [code from which your are calling spring-boot application]

Comment: Added pom.xml and web mvc code

Comment: when you say you want to display span_id and trace_id on UI , does it mean UI for your application or you can think of something like zipkin where you can see and search based on span_id/trace_id etc.

Comment: Yes, we need to search based on span_id/trace_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to inject the `Tracer` bean and then if you call `tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString()` and `tracer.currentSpan().context().spanIdString()`.

Comment: Can we use this trace_id and span_id while tracing the logs? I mean we need to have a correlation ID which we have use in UI (like zipkin)

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand the problem. If you use Sleuth you get full log correlation, the logs do contain trace id and span id. Have you tried using this before asking the question? Or you did use it and you don't see the trace id and span id in the logs? Have you changed the default logging format? In general if you just add starter-sleuth to the classpath you get the logging correlation out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using Sleuth but the actual problem is that I am not getting trace/span-id in spring MVC project even after changing the format of logs. I am able to see the correlation id in spring boot project but not in spring MVC project.

Comment: Sleuth will not work without spring boot. You can use project Brave directly instead

Comment: Do I need to configure Brave in both spring MVC and spring Boot application?

Comment: No. Sleuth is a boot based library so it will work out of the box. With a pure spring app you need to add brave and set it up yourself